# Javascript - free a memorized function

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I must say that I do not know the right terminology, so please forgive my some mistakes.
What I have is a Table with rows. The last editable column of the *last* row in the table is enabled with a TabKey which automatically creates a new row.

```
function enableTab() {
  lastEditable = currentTable
    .find("tr")
    .find('textarea, .cleanbox-editable-cell')
    .not(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).parent().css("display") == "none";
    })
    .last();

  lastEditable.unbind("keydown");
  lastEditable.keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    createNewRow();
  };
};

function createNewRow() {
  createRow();
  enableTab();
}
```

When the new row is created, the lastEditable variable is re-calculated.
What I want is lastEditable to be associated only to the last column of the last row. Anyway, what happens is that a new row is created, and both the new and previous rows' last columns are furnished with the function to create new rows, when I want only the *new* row to be be able to perform such a function.

So, in my opinion, what happens is that: everytime a new row is created, the *variable* lastEditable is rightly associated to the last column of the new row. But the function of the *object* previously associated to that same variable is not deleted: it simply doesn't have a name anymore.

Am I kind of right? How can I delete an object?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
lastEditable.keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    delete lastEditable;
    createNewRow();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unbinding the event handler, then immediately reapplying the same event handler to the same element. You need to re-organise your code so that you bind the event handler to the new element as you create the new row http://jsfiddle.net/2fLrsjcz/

```
var currentTable = $('table');

function bindKeyDown(lastEditable) {
    lastEditable.keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 9) {
            createNewRow($(this));
        }
    });
}

function getLastEditable() {
    return currentTable
    .find("tr")
    .find('textarea, .cleanbox-editable-cell')
    .not(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).parent().css("display") == "none";
    })
    .last();
}

function createNewRow($lastEditable) {
    var newEditable = $lastEditable.parent().parent().clone().appendTo(currentTable);
    $lastEditable.unbind("keydown");
    bindKeyDown(getLastEditable());
}

bindKeyDown(getLastEditable());
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve this post that may be useful to others, studying Lee's code I have solved my problem just moving lastEditable.unbind("keydown") into .keydown(function(e) {}), as following:

```
function enableTab() {
  lastEditable = currentTable
    .find("tr")
    .find('textarea, .cleanbox-editable-cell')
    .not(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).parent().css("display") == "none";
    })
    .last();

  lastEditable.keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    lastEditable.unbind("keydown");
    createNewRow();
  };
};

function createNewRow() {
  createRow();
  enableTab();
}
```